# Two component are mixing in react after using param in path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component

In the react I am using two component with two different path.
When I use this code to route the component it works fine ..

```
<Router>
<Provider store={store}>
        <Route exact path="/ID/" component={App}/>
        <Route  path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
</Provider>
</Router>
```

But when I am using ID as a parameter then Register and Login  components are  mixing with App component on their path "/register" and "/login"  as shown in image.  On path "/:ID" everything is fine.

```
<Router>
<Provider store={store}>
        <Route exact path="/:ID/" component={App}/>
        <Route  path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
</Provider>
</Router>
```

[image: Two component are mixing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the routes in `<Switch>`. It will render the first matched route and will ignore any subsequent matches.

Also you should put your `<Route exact path="/:ID/" component={App}/>` route at the very and of `<Switch></Switch>` wrapper, because `/login` and `/register` are recognized a match for `/:ID`.

```
<Router>
   <Provider store={store}>
      <Switch>
         <Route  path="/login" component={Login}/>
         <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
         <Route exact path="/:ID/" component={App}/>
      </Switch>
   </Provider>
</Router>
```